# Unable to read repository at https://ecd-plugin.github.io/update/content.xml in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install decompiler in Eclipse Mars but I am getting Unable to read repository at `https://ecd-plugin.github.io/update/content.xml` everytime. I tried to install any other plugins too from the marketplace but I got same error. Also i tried to access the url from Eclipse Internal Web Browser and I am able to access the page. Not sure why i am getting this error.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which JRE are you using (I'm thinking in regard to https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/)? And why such an *old* release--it's from 2015?

Comment: I am using jre7 for eclipse...

Comment: Your Eclipse is 11 release and 5 years behind (as nitind alread said). Also Java 7 is no longer maintained. Not only because of the issue you face, you should upgrade asap.